# Change app bundle identifier and firebase connection problem

Tags: ios, firebase

i have to change my app bundle identifier, so i added a new ios app to firebase project with new bundle identifier.
I downloaded new googleservice-info.plist instead old file but my app can not connect to firebase server. Here is the error

error code : 403

domain : global

message : Requests from this ios client application my-new-bundle-identifier are blocked

reason = forbidden

is replacing googleservice-info.plist enough? did it cache? how to complely remove it from my app.

Comment: Have you updated the API Key in `AppDelegate`, OAuth-client secret key in plist?

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal : please tell me how to update API key and OAuth0client secret key

Comment: Have you updated reverse client id in URL types?

Comment: There is nothing in URL Types.